# T-SQL : treat int as weekday

Tags: t-sql, casting, type-conversion, integer, weekday

```
DECLARE @weekDayCounter int = 7;
SELECT @weekDayCounter + 1
--returns  8
```

The question is how do I make T-SQL treat `@weekDayCounter` as a weekday number without writing case or if statements?

I want to know if there is a way to `CONVERT/CAST` that int into a weekday datatype, or have a number series that resets to the first number when the max number is exceeded (e.g. 31st of December + 1 day = 1st of January not 32 December OR 23:59 + 1hr = 00:59 not 24:59)

So

```
SELECT @weekDayCounter + 1 --returns 1
```

Any answers are appreciated!

Comment: There isn't a "weekday" datatype in SQL Server. When used with the DayOfWeek parameter, the `DATEPART` function returns an integer that represents an ordinal of days of the week with the week-starting day depending on how your server is configured. The question then becomes "why do you want to avoid particular statements?"

Comment: @paneerakbari Because it would look cleaner to just ```convert/cast``` it instead of writing an ```if``` statement or a ```case``` expression.(in my humble opinion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to increment a value in the range `1` through `7` you can use the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
set @WeekDayCounter = @WeekDayCounter % 7 + 1;
```

Comment: Looking back on this answer, I have to say I like your solution and commend you.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd just like the number to wrap back to 1 every time it passes 7, one option would be:

```
SELECT  @weekDayCounter - (7 * FLOOR(@weekDayCounter/7))+1
```

It just subtracts out 7 * (the number of times 7 goes into @weekDayCounter)

Comment: Thank you! That solves it! I incorporated it like shown below:
```SET @weekDayCounter= @weekDayCounter- (7 * FLOOR(@weekDayCounter/7))+1```
P.S. using ```SET @weekDayCounter -= (7 * FLOOR(@weekDayCounter/7))+1``` symbol will return ```-1``` for a reason I am not aware of. Do you know why?

Comment: Glad it helps!  If you're trying to count backwards, I guess this would have to be rewritten, I'm not immediately clear on what tweak you'd have to make to make that work, but i'll try to think through it